# JPA autocompletion is not working in Intelliji spring-boot kotlin project

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

Created a simple JPA spring boot application like the attached screenshot, I found the JPA auto completion is not working anymore as java JPA.

Any suggestions to make this auto completion work?
It works for java code.

java Code
[image: java Code]

Kotlin code

[image: kotlin code]

Comment: Are you sure autocomplete works on finder methods? Even in Java...

Comment: Pretty sure it works for me. Please look at another screenshot.

Comment: Cool, just checked my java project, you are right...doesn't work with Kotlin. Upvoted!

Comment: Which version of IDEA do you use? Actually, it is implemented for Kotlin only in 2018.3

Comment: Did you try the combination "ctrl + o"? That should generate the stubs for all overrideable methods. Something which you can try always is to invalidate the caches. That helps in 99% of all wired IDE bugs.

Comment: I am using the latest version of intellij

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar if the latest means 2018.2 then it shouldn't work because it is not implemented, you could try 2018.3 EAP.

Comment: same issue here, it does not work, anyone have solution?

Comment: Not sure if anyone mentioned this but, I believe JPA autocomplete features come from a plugin that is only available to enterprise edition (EE) apps which for intellij are usually only supported by the Ultimate IDEA versions https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/jakarta-persistence-jpa.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your methods as `override fun ...` for IDEA to suggest JPA methods.